# Gradle: app does not see code imported from second level of submodule

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I have a problem with transitive dependencies in my project.
There is an app (main) module which includes gradle library module A, which  includes module B.

The problem is that app does not see classes inside module B.
Module A of course see classes from B, but app does not.

Dependencies should be transitive by default, but nothing happens.

So app gradle file has:

```
implementation project(path: ':A')
```

Module A has:

```
implementation project(path: ':B')
```

If I add:
    implementation project(path: ':B') 
to the app gradle file, it works, but i must exclude this, since I will use product flavors and this does not works for me anymore.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `implementation`, the classes won't be accessible from the modules which use it.

In order to expose the classes from sub-modules, you should replace `implementation` with `api`

In module 'A', use:

```
api project(':B')
```

In module 'app', use:

```
implementation project(':A')
```